# How do I substitute lists in list?

Tags: list-manipulation

i can substitute lists in list as follows
ihave 3 lists

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {2, 1, 3};
c = {1, 3, 2};
```

and i have a list
w = {x + y + z, y, x + z};

i do it

```
w /. {x -> a, y -> b, z -> c}
```

the result is as follow

```
{{4, 6, 8}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 5, 5}}
```

but i want it as follows

```
{x1+y1+z1,y2,x3+z3}={4, 1, 5}
```

Comment: What are a,b,c?

Comment: Oh, I see the update. Makes sense now.

Comment: You could also apply `Diagonal` to your result to extract the correct entries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I do if it was n elements in list w and lists a,b,c ?

As an example:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = {1, 2, 3, 5};
b = {2, 1, 3, 6};
c = {1, 3, 2, 8};
amat = {a, b, c};
w = {x + y + z, y, x + z, y - z}; (* e.g. *)
MapThread[ReplaceAll, {w, 
  Thread[{x, y, z} -> #] & /@ Transpose[amat]}]
```

> `{4, 1, 5, -2}`

Answer (score 3):

Since there's no clear pattern here I suggest the following simple solution based on [Part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
{a[[1]] + b[[1]] + c[[1]], b[[2]], a[[3]] + c[[3]]}
```

> `{4, 1, 5}`

Comment: What I do if it was n elements in list w and lists a,b,c

Comment: @Willymith if you had a larger list with larger sublists in the suggested approach here you'd have to do it manually. Note that I already mentioned there's not a clear pattern to follow in order to build the final/resulting list. Also, note that in the other approach you'd still need to build the equivalent of the matrix `{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}` by hand in case of larger lists. If there were a clear pattern, we'd have a different approach

Answer (score 2):

You could use Pick. You want

```
{x1+y1+z1,y2,x3+z3}
```

so, let's start by getting things aligned nicely:

```
Transpose[{x, y, z}]
(* {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}} *)
```

Now, let's create a new parallel matrix that sets which elements to keep and which to discard. In this case it could be

```
{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}
```

where 1 is keep and 0 is discard. Now we can use Pick:

```
Pick[Transpose[{x, y, z}], {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}, 1]
(* {{x1, y1, z1}, {y2}, {x3, z3}} *)
```

Now just sum each sublist:

```
Plus @@@ Pick[Transpose[{x, y, z}], {{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}, 1]
(* {x1 + y1 + z1, y2, x3 + z3} *)
```

**Edit**

Based on the update, replace x,y,z above with a,b,c

Answer (score 2):

Using `Apply`, `Function` and `Part` (as pointed out @bmf):

```
Apply[Function[{p1, p2, p3}, {p1[[1]] + p2[[1]] + p3[[1]], p2[[2]], p2[[3]] + p3[[3]]}], {a, b, c}]
(*{4, 1, 5}*)
```

Just to expand on @lericr's answer:

First, the variables:

```
varlist = {x, y, z};
l = Length[varlist];
vars = Transpose[
Table[Array[ToExpression[ToString[Part[varlist, i]] <> ToString[#]] &, l], {i, 1, l}]]
(*{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}}*)
```

Using `Association`:

```
mat = {a, b, c};
vars2 = ArrayReshape[Normal[Association[Thread[Flatten[vars] -> Flatten[mat]]]], Dimensions[vars]]
```

Finally, using `Pick` as pointed out @lericr:

```
Map[Composition[Apply[Plus, #] &, #[[All, 2]] &], Pick[Transpose[vars2], Normal[CoefficientArrays[{x + y + z, y, x + z}]][[2]], 1]]
(*{4, 1, 5}*)
```

Comment: Glad to see the 10-ways team up and running!!! Still in the middle of moving, hopefully I'll be fully operational in a month -give or take something :)

Comment: I'm also glad to see 10-ways team up and running. My best wishes for your move to end well. Greetings :)